Отслеживание закрытия WebApp Telegram
Нужно вешать функцию, которая будет срабатывать при закрытии WebApp в телеграме, я сделал это через
 window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
      // func
 });

но вопрос в другом, как обработать внеплановое/плановое закрытие телеграма, ибо в этом случае моё решение не работает.

Никак. Если внепланово выдернуть комп из розетки или батарею из телефона — обрабатывать что-либо будет уже некому

а если же планово закрыть телеграм?)
